# IMO 1992 Problem 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, contest-math

> For each positive integer $\,n,\;S(n)\,$ is defined to be the greatest integer such that, for every positive integer $\,k\leq S(n),\;n^{2}\,$ can be written as the sum of $\,k\,$ positive squares.

a.) Prove that $\,S(n)\leq n^{2}-14\,$ for each $\,n\geq 4$.

Now **solution** says for part a)

Representing $n^2$ as a sum of $n^2-13$ squares is equivalent to represent $13$ as sum of numbers of the form $x^2-1$,..

**I did not get why it is equivalent** ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
n^2&=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-13}a_k^2\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-13}(a_k^2-1)+(n^2-13)
\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$$13=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-13}(a_k^2-1)$$